# Cauchy-Riemann Equations - why $f'(z_o) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z_o)$ implies that f is differentiable at $z_o$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, partial-derivative

I'm trying to understand part b of [this proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r51dM.jpg).  The only line I don't understand is the sentence starting with "To prove the statement in (b)..."

If someone could clarify why that line is true I could ask a good follow up question.